# Is there a newer version for BlenRig add on?

Tags: rigging

I use this plugin called BlenRig for rigging objects. It was developed for Blender version 2.8, I use the newest version, ,2.92.0 I couldn't find a newer version of this BlenRig pugin. If someone can help, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The author is currently working on a new version. Quote from [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/blenrig-5-public-release/660103/410) thread:

**Juan Pablo Bouza**, 17th March 2021:

> The working version would be the one I posted a couple of days ago:
>
> https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/jfTvnK4no3dGC2VI7Udvep1fNcL.zip
>
> My advice is that you wait until a publish the Beta of the new BlenRig
> version, I’m really close to getting it ready. If I don’t finish it
> this week it will be next week, but we are really close. So don’t
> waste your time rigging a character with the version that is available
> right now

The last official version on github is [Blendrig 5](https://gitlab.com/jpbouza/BlenRig) for Blender 2.8. There is a bug and this version does **not** run for Blender 2.83 and higher. Blender 2.82 is ok. (Blender 2.92 I don't know). The [calc bone roll operation script does not work properly](https://gitlab.com/jpbouza/BlenRig/-/issues/22).
There is a question here at BSE, too: [Issue with execution of "Calc rolls" function](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/188167/107598)